# How to store data according to list size into another ArrayList?

Tags: java, android

I have below for loop

```
 for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
      JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);

      String id = c.getString("cat_id");
      String title = c.getString("cat_name");
      String image = c.getString("cat_img");

      mData.add(id);
      mData.add(title);
      mData.add(image);
      categoryHashMap.put(title, mData);
      mData.clear();
 }
 showLog("index: "+ categoryHashMap.size());

 if (jsonDataListener != null) {
       //   jsonDataListener.onClickData(tempList);
 }
```

mData is ArrayList. Now contacts.length is 7. but after completing for loop mData size is showing 21. which is correct because obviously there are 3 fields, which is id, title and image. but what I want is I want to store that data into another arraylist, but that new arraylist size should be 7 and by exapanding each index/sie, there should be 3 fields. so, I think it'll be like this:

```
 private List<String> mData;
 private  List<List<String>> tempList;
```

but the problem is that size is showing 0!

I tried with hashmap also ( `private  Map<String, List<String>> categoryHashMap = new HashMap<>();`), that 1st param is string and 2nd is list, but it's not make it.

Output should be:
In new arraylist

Index 0 -> id1
     title1
     image1

Index 1 -> id2
     title2
     image2

....

EDIT:
Full code:

```
 private List<String> mData;
    private  List<List<String>> tempList;
    private  Map<String, List<String>> categoryHashMap = new HashMap<>();



private void getTextFromJSON(String jsonParsingString) {
        if (jsonParsingString != null) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonParsingString);

                // Getting JSON Array node
                JSONArray contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray("data");

                // looping through All data
                mData.clear();
                for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);

                    String id = c.getString("cat_id");
                    String title = c.getString("cat_name");
                    String image = c.getString("cat_img");

                    mData.add(id);
                    mData.add(title);
                    mData.add(image);

                   /*for (int j=i; j<i+3; j++ ) {
                       categoryHashMap.put(title, mData);
                   }*/
                    tempList.add(mData);

                }
                showLog("index: "+ tempList);

                    if (jsonDataListener != null) {
                     //   jsonDataListener.onClickData(tempList);
                    }

            } catch (final JSONException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                mActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(mContext.getApplicationContext(),
                                "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage(),
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show();
                    }
                });

                if (jsonDataListener != null) {
                    jsonDataListener.onJSONParsingError(e.getMessage());
                }

            }
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't get JSON from server.");
            mActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(mContext.getApplicationContext(),
                            "Couldn't get json from server. Check LogCat for possible errors!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                }
            });
            if (jsonDataListener != null) {
                jsonDataListener.onJSONParsingError("Couldn't get json from server. Check LogCat for possible errors!");
            }


        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below implementation

```
List<String> mData;
List<List<String>> tempList = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
    mData = new ArrayList<>();

    JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);

    String id = c.getString("cat_id");
    String title = c.getString("cat_name");
    String image = c.getString("cat_img");

    mData.add(id);
    mData.add(title);
    mData.add(image);

    tempList.add(mData);
}
```

**Now `tempList` size is 7 and each one contain 3 items**

[image]

Comment: temp list size is 7, but when I exapnd for each index it is showing 21 size

Comment: Add your screenshot please. Definitely you missed something

Comment: Inside for loop initialize `mData` . Add this `mData = new ArrayList<>();` Or replace your for loop with my one will also solve the problem

Comment: but I want to pass mData outside the for loop as well!

Comment: Please specify the reason to pass `mData` outside loop. I don't find any meaning. Can you clear your requirement please?

Comment: because if I'll pass templist, it is not "Category" object type! (Category is my model class)

Comment: Not clear yet. What do you do with `mData` outside `getTextFromJSON`

Comment: That is working, but now bacause of this I'm getting compiler error. Now I need to convert String type to Category type, which is my model class. How can I do that? I'm not asking another question because you already know my problem. Please help me.

Comment: Add your `Category` class

Comment: Can you please check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62619895/how-to-get-image-path-which-is-stored-and-downloaded-by-glide-using-url-in-andro

Comment: Can you help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62783444/why-does-multipart-pdf-is-not-able-to-upload-in-api-using-retrofit-2-in-android

Answer (score 1):

Create a separate class to hold your 3 fields. For example name it as

```
class TempData{

  private String id;
  private String title;
  private String image;


 //getters and setters

 }
```

Then assign your id, title, image to this class.

```
  TempData tempData = new TempData();
  //set your id,title,image using setters
```

And make your list as bellow

```
  private List<TempData> mData;
```

Now add the tempData object to this list

```
   mData.add(tempData);
```

Comment: I already have model class, but the problem is I want to pass that new arraylist into that adapterclass parametrixed constructor, so that I can set image and title into recyclerview adapter

Comment: Try the above mentioned method.

Comment: You need to clear your mData for each loop.. Therefore add mData.clear(); inside your loop

Comment: That is working, but now bacause of this I'm getting compiler error. Now I need to convert String type to Category type, which is my model class. How can I do that? I'm not asking another question because you already know my problem. Please help me.

Comment: Where is your category model mentioned above.. please specify your problem directly..

Comment: Can you please help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62619895/how-to-get-image-path-which-is-stored-and-downloaded-by-glide-using-url-in-andro

Comment: Can you help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62783444/why-does-multipart-pdf-is-not-able-to-upload-in-api-using-retrofit-2-in-android

Answer (score 1):

Because you are adding string individually as item of the list.

```
                mData.add(id);
                mData.add(title);
                mData.add(image);
```

And your list type is String  `List<String> mData` that should be custom class like this.

```
  List<Cat_Model> mData
```

And `Cat_Model` class should contain three variable `id`,`title` and `image`.use the `setter` method to initialize the variable.

```
  public class Cat_Model{

   @SerializedName("cat_id")
   @Expose
   private String catId;
   @SerializedName("cat_name")
   @Expose
   private String catName;
    @SerializedName("cat_img")
    @Expose
   private String catImg;

   public String getCatId() {
   return catId;
  }

 public void setCatId(String catId) {
 this.catId = catId;
}

public String getCatName() {
 return catName;
}

public void setCatName(String catName) {
  this.catName = catName;
 }

 public String getCatImg() {
 return catImg;
 }

 public void setCatImg(String catImg) {
 this.catImg = catImg;
  }

 }
```

Comment: That is working, but now bacause of this I'm getting compiler error. Now I need to convert String type to Category type, which is my model class. How can I do that? I'm not asking another question because you already know my problem. Please help me.

Comment: Can you please help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62619895/how-to-get-image-path-which-is-stored-and-downloaded-by-glide-using-url-in-andro

Comment: Can you help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62783444/why-does-multipart-pdf-is-not-able-to-upload-in-api-using-retrofit-2-in-android

Answer (score 1):

Use below code:

```
    private  List<List<String>> tempList; // your array list
    for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);

        String id = c.getString("cat_id");
        String title = c.getString("cat_name");
        String image = c.getString("cat_img");
        List<String> mData = new ArrayList<>();

        mData.add(id);
        mData.add(title);
        mData.add(image);
        // Add your mData into your tempList
        tempList.add(mData);
        //categoryHashMap.put(title, mData);
    }
```

**Update:**
From your full code move `private  List<List<String>> tempList;` inside your function and move `List<String> mData` inside your loop like above.

Comment: @PriyankaSingh . move your list declaration inside function.

Comment: That is working, but now bacause of this I'm getting compiler error. Now I need to convert String type to Category type, which is my model class. How can I do that? I'm not asking another question because you already know my problem. Please help me.

Comment: @PriyankaSingh Category type must be some static list of constants, create one function which return Category type from string, you can create Enum for your Category type or another way.
If still issue ask another question with that part of code where you are converting ur list to pojo classes.

Comment: Can you please help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62619895/how-to-get-image-path-which-is-stored-and-downloaded-by-glide-using-url-in-andro

Comment: Can you help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62783444/why-does-multipart-pdf-is-not-able-to-upload-in-api-using-retrofit-2-in-android